# Error el el fetchAll() por consulta

Tags: php, sql, pdo

saben que estoy haciendo una consulta a la base de datos pero al hacerla la pagina me da un error que no se de donde viene, me dice:

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool

y la consulta es:

```
 $consulta3 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE 
 SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL = " .$_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']. "");
$profesional_pro = $consulta3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

si alguien me puede decir en que falle se lo agradecería mucho, a y el select le hice un ECHO y si me trae lo que quiero.

Comment: Diria que la consulta esta mal simplemente... mira de asignarla previamente a una variable y hacer un echo de la variable para ver si los datos pasados por $_SESSION son correctos, o bien aprovechar ese echo para realizar al consulta via phpmyadmin y ver si da algun error

Comment: los datos del $_SESSION vienen correctamente, tu me dices que a eso que dice '.$_SECCION['sucursal_seccion'].' lo asigne a una variable antes??

Comment: digo que hagas esto: `$var1 = "SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE 
 SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL = " .$_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']; echo $var1; die();` y verifiques lo que te sale... si lo ves correcto lo copias y lo pegas en el phpmyadmin y a ver si la consulta es correcta alli tambien.

Comment: duda por preguntar donde va en el phpmyadmin?? porque en el echo si me funciona bien

Comment: si tienes phpmyadmin lo pones en la pestaña llamada SQL y ejecutas la consulta con el boton Ejecutar

Comment: Ahora que lo veo, si el resultado de $_SESSION['sucursal_seccion'] es un nombre con espacios deberias entrecomillarlo en la query

Comment: yaya si pero mismo en que tabla o directamente en la que tiene todas las tablas?

Comment: En cualquier pestaña SQL mientras sea la base de datos correcta

Comment: lo que trae el $_SECCION es un string si

Comment: Es decir: ` $consulta3 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE 
 SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL = '" .$_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']. "'");`  Fíjate que he entrecomillado $_SESSION con comillas simples

Comment: es que si lo mando asi al SQL  $var1 = "SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE   SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL = " .$_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']; echo $var1; die(); me tira si un error

Comment: no con comillas simples no me deja

Comment: eso no, claro, jeje... tienes que mandarle el resultado del echo que te sale en pantalla despues del die()... ago asi como `SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL = Madrid`

Comment: Mejor te lo pongo como respuesta a ver si lo ves

Comment: ya me dio bien si, si trae bro

Comment: Comprueba mi respuesta, haz un corta pega en tu código y prueba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema me parece que está relacionado con la falta de comillas en el string que resuelve $_SESSION.

Ahora esta así:

```
$consulta3 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL = " .$_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']. "");
```

Pero deberia ser así:

```
$consulta3 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL = '" .$_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']. "'");
```

para que el string quede entrecomillado correctamente.

Comment: eso esooooooooooooooooooooooo, ahi quedo gracias

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)

Answer (score 0):

No estás usando PDO *como debe ser*, ya que una de las ventajas es hacer más difícil [la inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php) y a la vez escribir consultas más fáciles evitando caracteres extras en las mismas.
Puedes usar diferentes estilos, [consultar documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
$consulta3 = "SELECT * FROM profesionales WHERE SUCURSAL_PROFESIONAL=?";
$params = array($_SESSION['sucursal_seccion']);
$stmt = $con->prepare($consulta3);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Ahora es solo cuestión de recorrer el objeto devuelto

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
    // Lo que quieras con la fila $row
}
```

O también se puede traer todo el resultado como un array.
[!] No recomendado para consultas grandes:

```
$profesional_pro = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```